# Текст в списке переходит на новую строку

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```css
main>ul>li {
  list-style-image: url(http://www.forumklassika.ru/images/pagination/next-right.png);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Текст:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Текст</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Текст</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Заголовок</h1>
      <p>Текст</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Здесь все отображается как надо. Но на сайте маркеры находятся снаружи (list-style-position: outside не задано). В чем может быть проблема?
Вот как выглядит на сайте (https://nikitaknyazev.ru/steps.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовал добавить list-style-position: inside, но тогда весь текст смещается под маркер

Comment: _Здесь все отображается как надо_ - так если здесь все отображается как надо - с чем помочь?!

Comment: В примере в jsfiddle отображается корректно. Но тоже самое на сайте отображается совсем по другому. Прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Так может быть стоит предоставить хотя бы ссылку на сайт?

Comment: https://nikitaknyazev.ru/steps.html

Comment: А где пример, который _в jsfiddle отображается корректно_?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60144/discussion-between-nikita-knyazev-and-ags17).

Comment: вообще косяк у вас , `h1` не может быть применён больше одного раза , но можно за то поместить его в тег `p` и задать ему `class` и присвоить этому какие угодно стили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jsfiddle так же по логике и отрабатывает. Добавьте просто margin-left: 20px для элементов списка (li)